# How can I insert an empty value instead of date?

Tags: html

I have a user input: "type = date" and I have some cases in which I need to insert a space instead of date. Is that possible using "type=date" or it requires only a date?

Comment: then use type="text", this will works right?

Comment: Yes, sure it'll work but I need the date type...

Comment: use type="text" with pattern is empty string or date format